# Centre and Layout Pages without a wrapper and having a footer

Tags: css

After reading this article http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres
I have decided to follow what it says and eliminate wrappers from my site design. Gave my body element a width, give html and css different background colours.etc

Things are working fine, I'm really impressed by it until I need to add a footer. At this moment, I'm kind of stuck. Since my footer tag has to be inside the body element, it's width only extend to the width of the body element (which is 600px). and the white box still surrounds my footer instead of ending before my footer as expected.

Is there a way I can get the footer to be like any footer you see on other sites (where the footer span the full width of the page in a different colour, without going back to wrapper divs?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You're restricted to a *max* width of `600px`, so the max width is `600px`, which isn't `100%` width. Add a wrapper ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsbin.com/ifika6)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<style> 
    html    {height: 100%; width: 680px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;
         background: #c72;}
    body    { min-height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 20px;
         border: 1px solid black; border-width: 0 1px;
         font: 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         color: #333;
         background-color: #eee;}
    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        background: #ccc
    }
</style> 
<body> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..

    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

Be aware that it's not ["sticky"](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/): http://jsbin.com/ifika6/2

Comment: I gave up and decided not to add a footer in the end, but your answer came the nearest to it. +1 :).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set `padding-bottom: 0` for the body and `margin-bottom: 0` for the footer div (or whatever you used), that should make it touch the bottom.

Comment: The OP asked how they could make a 100% width footer on a page where the `<body>` is fixed-width.

Comment: @Blender: "and the white box still surrounds my footer instead of ending before my footer as expected."

Answer (score 0):

If I were you then I will do the following things:

THE CSS

```
.wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:980px;/*your width will goes here*/
    background: green;
}

.footer{
    background: red; /*your style will goes here*/
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    MainContent will goes here.....
</div>
<div class="footer">
    this is footer..... 
</div>
```

Hope it helps you to solve your problem......

Comment: My aim is to see if there a way to get rid of the wrapper in this situation since that the point of that article. But having the footer span the whole page as well. :)

Comment: Two things come into my mind. 1.The "Table" which should not use and 2. The "Liquid" CSS layout. you can check the second option tutorial here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0916.htm